# When I add a score, the scoreText just rapidly displays the scores added to itself

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am a newbie and I am making this android game that if the player has destroyed a meteor, a score is added to its score, well the problem is that I want to display the score in my scoreText, but whenever I initialize it in my Update(), it rapidly adds the score in my scoreText. I just cant figure out how to properly add the score to my scoreText This is my game manager script

```cs
     public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
     {

          public static int displayScores;
          public int displayTheScore;
 
          public Text scoreText;
 
          // Start is called before the first frame update
          void Start()
          {
              scoreText.text = "" + displayScores;
          }
          void Update(){
              scoreText.text = "" + displayScores;
              displayScores += Meteor.displayScore;
          }
     }
```

And this is the script to making the conditions that if the meteor is detroyed, a score is added to displayScore depending on the hits to the meteor

```
 public class Meteor : MonoBehaviour
 {
 
     public int maxHealth; 
     public int currentHealth;
     public float speed;
     public int hits = 0;
     public int score = 100;
     public static int displayScore;
     public int display;
     public int currentHealthChecker;
     public static int counter;
 
     public Health healthBar;
 
     public GameObject canvas;
     public Transform effect;
 
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         currentHealth = maxHealth;
         healthBar.setMaxHealth(maxHealth);
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         transform.Translate(Vector2.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);
     }
     public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
         if(other.transform.tag == "bullet"){
             hits++;
             canvas.SetActive(true);
             currentHealth--;
             currentHealthChecker = currentHealth;
             healthBar.setHealth(currentHealth);
             display = displayScore;
             if(currentHealth <= 0){
                 displayScore = score * hits;
                 Instantiate(effect, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
                 Destroy(this.gameObject);
                 counter++;
                 canvas.SetActive(false);
             }
             Destroy(other.gameObject);
         }
         if(other.transform.tag == "bottom"){
             Destroy(this.gameObject);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing in update method, that why it keeps adding rapidly because update is called every frame. instead of adding in update, add the score value in ontriggerenter2d method.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
     if(other.transform.tag == "bullet"){//add score}
```